# Save jQuery callback functions in a separate file

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, callback

Probably I missed something, but lets say I have this:

```
$('a.delete').click(function(){
   resp=window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
   if(resp)
       return true;
   else
       return false;
}
```

Now, I want to save that callback function into a separate js file, because I will use it in several pages. My logic told me to do this:

```
$('a.del').click(delete_element());
```

Having my js file like this:

```
function delete_element(){
   resp=window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
   if(resp)
       return true;
   else
       return false;
}
```

This doesn't work. Everytime my page loads, it displays the confirm window, even if I haven't clicked the link.

It is clear that my logic failed this time. What am I missing?

Comment: point of style: you could just do this: `return confirm('...');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $('a.del').click(delete_element());

That is calling the function delete_element() and hoping for a function to be returned.

```
$('a.del').click(delete_element);
```

That (note the missing ()) will set the click handler to delete_element.

Comment: Perfect. Easier than I thought. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

try;

```
$('a.delete').click(function(){
  delete_element()
}
```

**edit**

I'd be passing the reference to the element to remove to the delete_element function and removing it from there as the name of the function says delete_element not ask_to_delete_element.

Comment: +1, Wrap the function inside an anonymous function, because its not wrapped within a function the JavaScript engine is probably parsing the function during the time it does not exists, by wrapping it in a function the engine will only parse the function at the time of the click. witch would obv be when your page is fully loaded

Comment: It works, however, it wont pass the result to the parent function. I will probably have to grab the result of delete_element() and return true or false to the parent accordingly.

Comment: switching htat to "return delete_element()" would fix the true/false thing.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
function deleteElement() {
   return window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
}

$('a.delete').click(deleteElement);
```

Or if this is standard behavior for your pages:

```
$('a.delete').live('click', function() {
   return window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
});
```